# Splitting a multi-line environment variable into lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I have the following problem:
I execute a windows batch file on a Jenkins server and have to split a multi-line environment variable (set vía a Jenkins parameter) into single lines. Each line is part of a parameter list for another program:

Jenkins textbox parameter:

```
-foo 224 -bar "Some parameter with spaces"
-foo 225 -bar "another param"
```

Should lead to the following calls inside Jenkins:

```
myprog.exe -baz 0 -meow -foo 224 -bar "Some parameter with spaces"
myprog.exe -baz 0 -meow -foo 225 -bar "another param"
```

I tried to split it with `for /F` but did not have any success. Searching did not turn up anything useful, anything I tried gave me syntax errors or just printed the first line.

This is among the things that I tried:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in ("%varname%") do
```

Gives me syntax errors, because that variable already contains quotes.

```
echo %varname%
```

Does only output the first line of the variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should show your code how you retrieve the parameter and how you try to split them

Comment: My solution for this kind of stuff in the Gnu Win32 Utils. All the command line power of your *nix right in Windows cmd.exe. I mostly use em for 'grep', but there's the full suite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FOR /F command takes the LF's inserted in the variable as lines separators (this is the natural behavior of FOR /F command), so nothing additional is required in order to process such variable with FOR /F:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a variable containing line breaks.
set LF=^
%empty line 1/2%
%empty line 2/2%
set "str=The quick brown!LF!fox jumps over!LF!the lazy dog."

set line=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("!str!") do (
   set /A line+=1
   echo Line !line!: %%a
)
```

The key here is expanding the variable with !exclamationMarks!; otherwise the LF will cut the %value%. Also, if you want *complete lines* separated by LF, use "delims=". Output example:

```
Line 1: The quick brown
Line 2: fox jumps over
Line 3: the lazy dog.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as reflex I propose you the following solution:

If python is installed (if not ... up to you to install it .. it is usefull ;-) )

in your batch line : 
Python MyScriptToExecuteEachLinesFromVar.py varname  "myprog.exe -baz 0 -meow"

With the script content:

```
import sys,os  # libraries used : system and operating system

if len(sys.argv)>0:                   # if arguments provided (at least the variable name)
  varname = sys.argv[1]               # the variable name is the second argument (0=script)
  prefix = " ".join(sys.argv[2:])     # the list of all others are the prefix.

  lines = os.environ[varname].split('\n')  # get the var and split lines 

  for f in lines : 
    print "execute:", prefix, f
    os.system(prefix+" "+f)                # execute each line with the given prefix.
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could `echo` the variable out to a temporary txt file, then process that txt file line-by-line using a `for /f` loop.  You should also use delayed expansion to prevent the line breaks from being evaluated inappropriately.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: // Test environment.  Create a variable containing line breaks.
set BR=^


:: // note: The two empty lines above are required.
set "str=The quick brown!BR!fox jumps over!BR!the lazy dog."

:: // Test environment ready.
:: // Output to temporary txt file.
>"%temp%\tmp.txt" echo(!str!

:: // Process the txt file line by line.
set "line=0"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%temp%\tmp.txt") do (
    set /a line += 1
    echo Line !line!: %%I
    rem // myprog.exe -baz 0 -meow %%I
)

:: // Delete temporary txt file.
del "%temp%\tmp.txt"
```

That should output

> Line 1: The quick brown
>
> Line 2: fox jumps over
>
> Line 3: the lazy dog.

---

Or if you'd rather avoid temporary files, you could invoke another runtime to supply the environment variable to a `for /f` loop.  Here's a JScript hybrid example.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: // Test environment.  Create a variable containing line breaks.
set BR=^


:: // note: The two empty lines above are required.
set "str=The quick brown!BR!fox jumps over!BR!the lazy dog."

:: // Test environment ready.
:: // Invoke JScript to read the environment variable and return it line-by-line
set "line=0"
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"') do (
    set /a line += 1
    echo Line !line!: %%I
)

:: // end main runtime
goto :EOF

@end // JScript portion simply echoes %str% from the context of the current process
WSH.Echo(WSH.CreateObject('WScript.Shell').Environment('PROCESS')('str'));
```

Output is the same as above.