# How to find total commas in the first line of a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I want create a batch file to find the total number of commas in the first line of text file.

Sample Text File
**input.txt**

```
12345,Bhavik
12323,Bhavik,Sanghvi
```

**Output**

```
1
```

I tried to surf net for this but couldnt find a solution, please help

Comment: iam not aware of batch programming but i found something helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158719/how-to-loop-through-comma-separated-string-in-batch

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103677/how-to-count-characters-in-a-text-file-using-batch-file  this pertains your cause

Comment: You have not asked a question, much less shown any evidence of trying to solve one.

Comment: I have not solved because i don't know how to do that. If i had known why would i ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read the first line
set /P "line=" < input.txt

rem Store it in a text file
> before.txt echo !line!

rem Store the line without commas in a second file
> after.txt echo !line:,=!

rem Get the difference in sizes between both files
set "diff="
for %%a in (before.txt after.txt) do (
   if not defined diff (
      set "diff=%%~Za"
   ) else (
      set /A "diff-=%%~Za"
   )
)
del before.txt after.txt

echo %diff%
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another simple solution to this question.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set LF=^


::Above 2 blank lines are critical - do not remove
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
set /p var=<input.txt
echo "%var:,="!cr!!lf!"..***..%">temp.file
find /c "..***.." <temp.file
del temp.file
```

Answer (score 0):

If, rather than being hampered by the awful Windows BATCH tools, you install `awk` from the Unix tools for Windows [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net), you can do this:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print NF-1;exit}' input.txt
```

That says... *"Run `awk` and use commas as the separator to divide fields. On line 1, print the number of fields on this line minus 1, then exit. Do that for file `input.txt`."*

`gawk` is just a slightly different version of `awk` if you get that one in the Unix Utils package. You may need to replace the single quotes with double ones to accommodate Windows' lack of abilities.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35826440.txt"
:: first method
SET /a count=0
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO SET "line=%%a"&GOTO got1
:got1
SET "line=%line:"=%"
IF NOT DEFINED line ECHO method 1: %count% found&GOTO method2
IF "%line:~-1%"=="," SET /a count+=1
SET "line=%line:~0,-1%"
GOTO got1
:: second method
:method2
SET /a count=-1
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO SET "line=%%a"&GOTO got2
:got2
SET "line=%line:"=%"
SET "line=%line:;=%"
SET "line=%line: =%"
SET "line=%line:,=x,x%"
FOR %%a IN (%line%) DO SET /a count+=1
ECHO method 2: %count% found

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35826440.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Two methods - both read the first line to `line`, then removes any `"` characters.

The first then mechanically loops, checking whether the last character is a comma, counting if it is and removing the last character until the string found is empty.

The second replaces all `;` and <kbd>Space</kbd> characters (for good measure, <kbd>Tab</kbd> could be removed too) and then replacing commas with `x,x`.

The result is that the only separators left are commas, and there will be 1 more item in the list so formed than there are commas.

Hence, start the counter at -1 and increment for each element found in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Next solution (similar to Magoo's second method) seems to treat even [˙cmd˙ and `.bat` poisonous characters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) supposed in input file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "infile=D:\bat\SO\files\35826440input.txt"   change to suit your circumstances
set /A "commacount=-1"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("%infile%") do (
  set "line=%%G"
  call :parseline
  if /I not "%~1"=="/all" goto :continue
) 
:continue
echo script continues here
ENDLOCAL
exit /B

:parseline
  rem treat unbalanced doublequote in next line
  set "lineToParse=%line:"=§%"
  set "lineToParse=%lineToParse:,=","%"
  set /A "commacount=-1"
  for %%g in ("%lineToParse%") do (
    set /A "commacount+=1"
    rem echo %line%, !commacount!, %%g    
  )
  echo %commacount% "%line%"
goto :eof
```

**Output** (with input file listing):

```
==> D:\bat\SO\35826440.bat
1 "12345,Bhavik"
script continues here

==> D:\bat\SO\35826440.bat /all
1 "12345,Bhavik"
2 "12323,Bhavik,Sanghvi"
3 "12323,Bhavik,Sanghvi,three"
0 "zero"
1 ",1 leading"
2 ",,2 leading"
1 "trailing,"
2 "2 trailing,,"
2 "2 middle,,mid"
4 "!OS!,!,!!,!!!,exclamations"
4 "%OS%,%,%%%,%%,percents"
8 "&,|,>,<,",",;,=,miscelaneous"
0 "unbalanced"doublequote"
script continues here

==> type D:\bat\SO\files\35826440input.txt
12345,Bhavik
12323,Bhavik,Sanghvi
12323,Bhavik,Sanghvi,three
zero
,1 leading
,,2 leading
trailing,
2 trailing,,
2 middle,,mid
!OS!,!,!!,!!!,exclamations
%OS%,%,%%%,%%,percents
&,|,>,<,",",;,=,miscelaneous
unbalanced"doublequote

==>
```