# How to include a carriage return character with a multiple line var in a windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I'm trying to write a file that will have arguments for an exec (putty) The problem is that the line feed trick is not working, how can i put a carriage return after each line avoiding the batch to interprets it as an enter.

```
set LF=^
set previousver=36
SET base=%fullver:1.2.0

set out=features:uninstall NOCFileLookup !LF
removeurl:mvn:org.NOC/NOCFileLookup-feature/%base%.%previousver%-SNAPSHOT/xml !LF
addurl mvn:org.NOC/NOCFileLookup-feature/1.2.0.37-SNAPSHOT/xml !LF
features:install NOCFileLookup!LF
config:edit NOCFileLookup !LF
config:propset context Testing !LF
config:update

@echo %out% > deployALL
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\PuTTY\putty.exe -ssh localhost -l karaf -pw karaf -P 8101 -m deployAll
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `set LF=^` trick needs two blank lines following to work.  Also, the syntax for retrieving a batch variable in the delayed expansion style is to use an exclamation mark **on both sides** of the variable name.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28992360/1683264 for an example of correct implementation of what you're trying to do.

But really, you're making more work for yourself.  Why must all lines be combined into a single variable with included line breaks?  The batch language isn't terribly welcoming for multi-line variable values the way JavaScript and other languages are.  If all you're doing is echoing several lines to a text file, then use several `echo` statements.

```
>deployAll (
    echo features:uninstall NOCFileLookup
    echo removeurl:mvn:org..NOC/NOCFileLookup-feature/%base%.%previousve‌​r%-SNAPSHOT/xml
    echo addurl mvn:org.NOC/NOCFileLookup-feature/1.2.0.37-SNAPSHOT/xml
    echo features:install NOCFileLookup
    echo config:edit NOCFileLookup
    echo config:propset context Testing
    echo config:update
)
```

Now isn't that much more readable?

Comment: thanks for the pointer, i did set `"out=features:uninstall NOCFileLookup!LF!removeurl:mvn:org..NOC/NOCFileLookup-feature/%base%.%previousver%-SNAPSHOT/xml!LF!addurl mvn:org.NOC/NOCFileLookup-feature/1.2.0.37-SNAPSHOT/xml!LF!features:install NOCFileLookup!LF!config:edit NOCFileLookup!LF!config:propset context Testing!LF!config:update"
> deployALL echo(!out!` But the output file only gets `features:uninstall NOCFileLookup !LF `

Comment: Did you `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` above the code snippet you posted?

Comment: @carlosgmercado Also, your `set "out=value"` line needs to be all on one line.  But you're really just making things harder for yourself.  See edit.

Comment: Are you opposed to using multiple `echo` statements the way I demonstrated above?  If so, why?

Comment: Your edit make sense and was my first option sadly most of this content came for maven variables, which will not set ( i don't know why) when there is a echo command within the line. That's why i went with the second option. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: on a second thought, let me try the above example, i was using @echo instead of echo.

Comment: You probably do need `@echo off` at the top of the script.  Otherwise, your `deployAll` file will include the actual word `echo` at the beginning of every line.